# How to pass the default time to time picker dialog fragment

Tags: android

I have created the time picker fragment.It shows the current timing in dialog box.I want to set the default time.what to do for setting the default timing in that dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Of [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html), to set the date.

Or you can set it at creation in the DatePickerDialog Constructor

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

declare you default time.. say 20:00

```
 mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
 int hour = 20;
 int minute = 0;
```

Then your dialog

```
 TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddMedicine.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
                    if(db.getAlarm3().contains(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute+" : 0")){
                        alarm3.setText( selectedHour + ":" +( selectedMinute+1));
                    }
                    else{
                        alarm3.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                    mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHour);
                    mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
                    mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

                    // alarm3.setText(String.valueOf(l3)+" ../.. "+String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour tim
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
```

Now the time picker dialog with appear with 20:00 on it.

Comment: I had to read that entire code just to see that you can use the constructor to set the default date, please add ("You can set default date on constructor").

Comment: @Nanoc I am sorry, but since he didn't post your code, I didn't know how much is required, so i posted the whole thing that works for me

Comment: Its work fine except am & pm.How to set am & pm as default manner?